# ImageGetter click

Tags: android, image

I have added an image to a Textview with ImageGetter and HTML text, and I want to implement a click event to it.

How can I do that? Can you provide an example? I could not find any.

Comment: Are you not able to use `setOnClickListener()`?

Comment: This will be on all the text. I want to do it on the image only...

Comment: As everyone else is suggesting, look at the documentation for implementing an `onClickListener`.  That should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be have a linear layout and add ImageView and TextView. Add setOnClickListener() on image only.

Please share the result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need the image to appear at end of textview (that has a long HTML text in it), and not static beneath the text.
ImageGetter solves it, but I did not find ANYWHERE a way to make it clickable.

Comment: Than develop a layout which full fill requirement and after that add listener on Image. Will this help ?